# Transfering UV Map

Tags: uv

I'm trying to transfer the UV map from an object to another. The two mesh have the same amount of vertices but it's different in faces and edges (one of them is just triangulated).

I tried to copy the UV from the *Link/Transfer Data* menu (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and I tried to *Transfer* UV *Mesh Data* none of them worked. I assume they work based on faces and not on vertices. If so is it possible to transfer it based on vertices or is there any other possible solution?